# Custom "binary" accuracy in a multi class model

Tags: python, tensorflow

I'm working with a classification model that outputs 10 classes.

The objective is to "regroup" the classes 1-5 and 6-10, the idea is to extract the argmax of both y_true and y_pred, then to inspect if they are in the same "super-group". This result is the accuracy

I tried this code but the result is 0 for the accuracy (the model is pre-trained and has no other problem)

```py
def test(y_true, y_pred):

    y_true_index = K.argmax(y_true, axis=-1)
    y_pred_index = K.argmax(y_pred, axis=-1)

    #I tried to set threshold to just 4 but the result is the same
    #I just tried it this way
    threshold = np.full(K.int_shape(y_true_index)[0], 4)

    y_true_bool = K.greater(y_true_index, threshold)
    y_pred_bool = K.greater(y_pred_index, threshold)

    matches = K.cast(K.equal(y_true_bool, y_pred_bool), 'int32')

    return K.mean(matches)


# after model is loaded

model.compile(opt, 
              loss=loss, 
              metrics=[test])

model.evaluate_generator(generator,
                         steps=steps,
                         verbose=1)
```

I'm not a real expert with axis, maybe the problem is there

Comment: Why not some equivalent of `c1, c2 = sum(pred[0:4]), sum(pred[5:9])`?

Comment: Edited the post